# Thingsboard - Count occurrences by value type of a single datapoint in a Timeseries Widget

Tags: thingsboard

My device sends a `fault` datapoint that contains the error message (a string, like `[E023] Check Sensor 5`), there are more than 200 different fault types...

```
{ 
   "fault" : "[E023] Check Sensor 5", 
   ... 
}
```

I want to include a graph or table in my Dashboard to indicate the occurrence count for each type of failure at a given time, to make it easier for the user to identify which ones should be given attention (like a [Pareto chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_chart)).

| Fault | Occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| [E023] Check Sensor 5 | 15 |
| [E105] Check Motor 6 | 3 |

Is it possible to do this without having to segregate into different datapoints using the Rule Chain or post-processing, without having to describe the messages (strings) one by one?

I achieved an approximate model using post-processing functions, but it is impractical with so many possible types of messages, and I wonder if there is a smarter way, especially because new types of failures may be included in the future.

[image]

[image]